# Shall we merge [catch2] and [catch-unit-test] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are two tags on Stack Overflow, [catch2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catch2) (141 questions) and [catch-unit-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catch-unit-test) (94 questions).

Based on the description of those tags and the content of the questions, one can conclude those are the same.

Comment: It this referring to the software at https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2 ?

Comment: Yes, both of them

Comment: @user yes, 13 hours ago at 2023-05-05 10:58:51Z (around when the [status-completed] tag was added).